# Nuget version mismatch for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures when using metapackage

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

I migrated an ASP.NET Core project from .NET Framework to .NET Core and in the process replaced the AspNetCore nuget packages with the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage. Originally I specified a version for it which worked fine, but VS whined about that telling me I'm not supposed to specify a version, so I removed it. Once I did that this happened:

> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.0.0.0,

These are coming from a Unit Test project which references my ASP.NET Core project. The ASP.NET Core project builds fine on its own. Now, I understand what this error means - somewhere in this Test project I must be referencing this package with a different version than what is provided by the metapackage. What I want to know is *where* is this package being referenced in my Test project? I have the following nuget packages in the Test project:

```
  <ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="2.2.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.10.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.3.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.3.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I don't see where any of these packages use any AspNetCore dependencies, so I'm at a loss as to where the version mismatch could be.

Comment: Hi Valuator, any update for  this issue? What the result if you create a new Test project to add the reference, same issue when building the test project?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I went and put back the version for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and am living with the compiler warning for now. I'll try a new Test project and post an update when I get a chance.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue?

Comment: No, it still does the same thing. I am just leaving the version reference for the metapackage in place and ignoring the warning about it.